# Macbook Pro Retina (Early 2015) does not recognize ubuntu partition as bootable

Tags: dual-boot, macbook-pro, refind

Hope everyone is well and had a good weekend.

I'm working on getting my **Macbook Pro Retina (early 2015)** to dual boot **Ubuntu Gnome 16.04**.  I've gone through the installation process listed at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro12-1/Wily) tutorial - the installation step is sparse and although I've followed it, I may have missed an ambiguous step.

I think my most likely culprits are either a bad install, either through an incomplete step towards the end, or through not properly setting up my file-system OR something with my grub.

So far I've done the following:

1. Shrunk my OSX partition in Disk Utility
2. Created a live bootable usb of Ubuntu
3. Install rEFInd - Laptop now boots straight to EFI, no holding alt key.
4. Booted to the USB (everything actually looks good - screen size, wifi etc. all work)
5. Jumped into GParted and created an ext4 partition mounted at /
6. Created a swap partition 1.5X the size of my ram (8gb ram => 12gb swap)
7. Follow installation app instructions, installing Ubuntu 16.04 onto the new partition.  (the installer closes but I get a never-ending spinning mouse (akin to the swirling rainbow on Mac)
8. Run `sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0080` so now `efibootmgr` lists the following output:

   `BootCurrent: 0080
   Timeout: 5 seconds
   BootOrder: 0080,0000
   Boot0000* Linux
   Boot0080* Mac OS X
   Boot0082* 
   BootFFFF*`

So this would ead me to believe that without rEFInd installed (uninstall it in OSX) I'll be able to boot straight to Ubuntu.  This is not the case.  In fact, Ubuntu doesn't show up at all on rEFInd.  I wouldn't think this part would really matter since I have an rEFInd isntalled, but I'm just going through the motions.

I should also mention that the device doesn't show up in the menu that shows up when you hold the alt key at boot, I only see Mac OS X and boot device, which is my live USB.

So can someone jump in and help me out?  I've installed Ubuntu plenty of times, but only once or twice in a dual-boot fashion, and never on a Mac.  It feels like I'm not doing the partitioning properly, or I've messed something up with the efibootmgr.

In case I missed something really simple, here's what my Gparted screen looks like:

[image: Gparted]

Comment: Is Boo00800* Mac OS X a typo?

Comment: Yes, I'm on a different machine from the one I'm trying to work on.

Comment: [edit] it so that someone with similar hardware may help you.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter but you are installing 16.04 and your instructions are for 15.10.

Comment: Ok. I don't have your hardware nor any experience with rEFInd but what jumps out at me is Boot current lists 0080, which shows as first in your boot order but there is no 0080 in the list. Perhaps changing the order to 0000,0800 will boot Ubuntu first and Mac OSX second.  Typos can ruin your day.

Comment: Right, I think the image shouldn't matter, the difference between the installers (as far as I know) is nil.  Ack, I thought I got that right, I'll double check and re-edit.  I've been putting off making this thread for this very reason :P

Comment: Hopefully the typo was when you issued `sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0080` and is the source of your problem.... `sudo efibootmgr` will output what you have instead

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case.  It was just a typo.  Regardless of boot order, does it seem at all strange that this is listed in efbootmgr but not in rEFInd?  I should also mention that it is not showing up in the menu that comes up when I hold alt at boot either.

Comment: [edit] that information into your question so that someone will read it in order to help us help you! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If Linux isn't showing up in rEFInd, chances are the right filesystem driver isn't installed. If you used ext4fs for Ubuntu (and it looks like you did), re-installing rEFInd in OS X should take care of the problem and get you going. If you used something other than ext4fs for Ubuntu, you'll need to manually install the correct driver. See the [rEFInd filesystem drivers page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html) for more on this subject.

If you need more help, please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried re-installing rEFInd, but it hasn't worked, and indeed I used an ext4fs, so 'll drop back into my installer USB and give the boot info script a shot.

Comment: I've run boot-info-script (cool tool, thanks for that info) and have it pasted here http://paste.ubuntu.com/23147998/

Comment: It looks like I reformatted before I took this snapshot.  I'll take it again after a fresh install and repost.  I'm not totally sure what I'm reading, but it looks a lot like what I see in Gparted live.  Is there anything I should look for here in particular?

Comment: There's no sign of an ext4fs EFI driver in the Boot Info Script output; however, it does sometimes miss that. Look for it manually by mounting `/dev/sdc1` (assuming the same drive assignments; it could be `/dev/sda1` or something else) and checking the `EFI/refind/drivers` directory. Also, knowing exactly what shows up in the rEFInd menu (including the captions that appear when you select the various first-line options) may be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have made a typo when you issued the command `sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0080` and that is the source of your problem. Check it with `sudo efibootmanager` and correct it as necessary.

If that's not it, you'll note that in the tutorial you say you followed the directions state clearly how to do this with the Ubuntu installer. Your attempt to do the partitioning with gparted likely missed an important step (perhaps a boot flag?) I don't see any reason why the instructions you are following for 15.10 wouldn't work for 16.04 but I don't have the hardware to test it.

If all else fails, install 15.10 and do an upgrade to 16.04 LTS which will give you the result you are looking for. I highly recommend letting the installer handle the partitions for you as outlined in the tutorial you were following.

Comment: It's possible.  If I can't figure things out soon, I'll definitely try 15.10, but I want to go for that LTS (there's also an app I like whose install plays much nicer with 16.04.)  Are you familiar with where the boot flag is set in the install process?

Comment: I know there are options in gparted to set a boot flag to a partition but It appears things are quite different with EFI so that's likely a poor guess